# Make asynchronous function with promises in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, axios

I have a function

```
function getImage(url, key) {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url,
    responseType: 'stream'
  }).then(response => {
    s3.upload({
      Key: key,
      Body: response.data,
      ContentType: response.data.headers['content-type'],
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }, (err, data) => {
      return key
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    return '';
  });
}
```

which downloades a remote image and uploads it to Amazon S3. I want it to return the generated key.

I want to use the function like this

```
const images = ['http://...', 'http://...', ...].map((url, i) => {
  return {
    url: getImage(url, i)
  }
});
```

Since my function `getImage()` could take a little while for every single URL, I guess I will have to use asynchronous calls so that I'm sure that the function is completely done before moving on to the next element (or am I misunderstanding something?).

I guess I have to use promises, so could a solution be something like this?

```
function getImage(url, key) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url,
      responseType: 'stream'
    }).then(response => {
      s3.upload({
        Key: key,
        Body: response.data,
        ContentType: response.data.headers['content-type'],
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }, (err, data) => {
        resolve(key);
      });
    }).catch(err => {
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
const images = ['http://...', 'http://...', ...].map((url, i) => {
  return {
    url: getImage(url, i).then(url => url).catch(err => [])
  }
});
```

## Edit

As mentioned in the comments, axios is a promise. Should the code then look like

```
function getImage(url, key) {
  return axios({
    method: 'get',
    url,
    responseType: 'stream'
  }).then(response => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.upload({
        Key: key,
        Body: response.data,
        ContentType: response.data.headers['content-type'],
        ACL: 'public-read'
      }, (err, data) => {
        if (!err) {
          resolve(key);
        } else {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  });
}
```

## Edit 2

The use case is that I'm fetching a lot of blog posts from a public API. So I am doing something like

```
const blogPostsOriginal = [
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
];

const blogPostsFormatted = blogPostsOriginal.map(blogPost => {
  return {
    title: blogPost.title,
    images: blogPost.images.map(url => {
      // upload image to S3
      return getImage(url);
    })
  };
});
```

So how would I structure the formatting of the array of blog posts? The problem is that if an error happened, I don't want to include the image in the array of images. I am not sure how to check this with promises.

Comment: When you invoke `getImage` it creates a promise via `axios`. If you wanted to use it multiple times for different URLs then you'd be fine as each promise will return as it is resolved. In that case, wrapping `axios` in a Promise object is redundant.

Comment: Ah I see. I have updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ECMAScript 2017 [`async` / `await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, you can quite easily accomplish this. Modifying the original form of your script, which you claim is working, it would look like the following:

```js
async function getImage(url, key) {
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url,
      responseType: 'stream'
    })

    await s3.upload({
      Key: key,
      Body: response.data,
      ContentType: response.data.headers['content-type'],
      ACL: 'public-read'
    }).promise()
  } catch (error) {
    // return error
    return key // since we don't have axios and s3 in here
  }

  return key
}

const blogPostsOriginal = [
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
  { title: 'Title', images: ['url1', 'url2'] },
];

Promise.all(blogPostsOriginal.map(async ({ title, images }) => {
  return {
    title,
    images: (await Promise.all(images.map(async (url) => {
      // get your key here somehow
      const key = Math.random().toString(36).slice(2, 12).padStart(10, 0)
      // upload image to S3
      return getImage(url, key)
    })))
    // after awaiting array of results, filter out errors
    .filter(result => !(result instanceof Error))
  }
})).then(blogPostsFormatted => {
  // use blogPostsFormatted here
  console.log(blogPostsFormatted)
})
```

To explain the bit about `s3.upload(...).promise()`, I got that from the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#promise-property).

#### References

- [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)
- [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but I am still not sure how to implement it with my use case. Can you help me with my question in my second edit?

Comment: Another quick question. Your original code silently fails on images that don't get fetched or uploaded and return a blank string as the key. Your modified code returns individual promises that either resolve or reject depending on their success, but you don't have anything that awaits their fulfillment collectively, which is why I used `Promise.all()`, but that would cause all of them to fail if any of them fails. Is that okay with you?

Comment: If one image fails, I just want it to be removed from the array. So I will just keep as many images as possible. I guess I will have to return `null` if it happens and then use `.filter(element => !!element)` or something like that to remove those that didn't work out, but it seems a bit hacky

Comment: When I am using `images: (await Promise.all(blogPost.images.map(async (url) => getImage(url) ))).filter(result => !(result instanceof Error)),`, I get `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: Note the parentheses around `await` in my answer. Those are necessary.

Comment: It was a mistake when I added to SO. I still get the error with `images: (await Promise.all(blogPost.images.map(async (url) => getImage(url) )))`

Comment: @Jamgreen check your node version. It requires 8.0 and above. Also see the stack snippet, there are no syntax errors.

Comment: I forgot the `async` keyword in `... blogPostsOriginal.map(async ({ ...`. Thanks!